# Output HTML from number of strings

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how best to organise an inline c# page that makes a number of DB connections and passes values to strings and need some advice.

So basically a CMS in use with my place of work only allows for inline code so I'm doing a course search page that hooks up to some stored procedures and passes the values to strings.

What would be the best way to handle three different stored procedure calls that output different bits of information to strings? In the old VB version I was passing info to strings then outputting them as one large string which probably isn't the best way to handle this.

The code currently goes in this rough format

```
Stored Procedure 1
Pass x values to string
string = "<p> + xString +</p>"

Stored Procedure 2
Pass y values to string
string = "<p> + yString +</p>"
```

Is there a smarter way for me to close off sections as each procedure section usually has a table involved or appends to one larger table and I'm just trying to see what people would suggest would be best practice.

Please note I'm really not much of a programmer and just dipping my toes so apologies if this is a school boy mistake.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of concatenating strings:

You could use a `StringBuilder`. This type allows you to Append and Insert text and then output all the text with the `ToString()` method.

`StringBuilders` are usually used when adding text to a string from within a loop. (I've read that using a StringBuilder is encouraged once you have over 10 concatenations)

Since you only have to append text to your string 3 times you can just use:
`String.Concat` or `yourString += string.Format("<p>{0}</p>", stringToBeAdded);`

In your case the texts may not be relevant to eachother, in which case there are other options available:

```
// Using an array (fixed size)
string[3] yourStrings;
yourStrings[0] = "first string";
yourStrings[2] = "last string";

// Using a list (dynamic sized)
var yourStrings = new List<string>();
yourStrings.Add(storedProcResult.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try and make the question clearer, however if I understand correctly  I think it would probably be best to create a stored procedure which runs the other stored procedures and stores the results in temp tables e.g.

```
INSERT INTO #MyTable1 EXEC procedure1 @param
INSERT INTO #MyTable2 EXEC procedure2 @param
INSERT INTO #MyTable3 EXEC procedure3 @param
```

Then in the same stored procedure run a simple select statement that concatenates the strings as desired and returns them to your inline code e.g.

```
SELECT CONCAT( MyTable1.emp_name, MyTable2.emp_middlename, MyTable3.emp_lastname ) AS Result
```